# Vector being perpendicular to two other vectors

Tags: vectors

I am having trouble finding a vector that is perpendicular to both $\vec a =-9\hat i+2\hat j+6\hat k$ and $\vec b =-2\hat i+\hat j+\hat k$.

Would it just be $18i + 2j + 6k?$

Comment: Hint: Do you know of any operation that takes two vectors and returns a vector that is perpendicular to both of them? Starts with a C ...

Comment: Actually the vector you have provided is the dot product(scalar) of the two vectors not the cross product(vector). Also dot product always yield in a scalar quantity, not a vector quantity

Comment: @DevanshKamra So, if the dot product yields a scalar, how can you say that the vector in this question is the dot product of the other two? If you mean “element-wise product,” that’s also called the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Comment: @amd, i am saying that he did element wise product, as in dot product, but instead of adding them all, he assigned the respective product to components $\hat i, \hat j, \hat k$

Comment: @DevanshKamra That’s not what you wrote, however: “... the vector ... **is** the dot product ...”

Comment: @amd, I'm sorry but I meant that.

Comment: You could check your own work: Do you know of any test that will tell you if two vectors are perpendicular? What do you get when you apply that test to your guess?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107016/discussion-between-devansh-kamra-and-amd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find any solution of

$$\begin{cases}-9x+2y+6z&=0,\\-2x+y+z&=0.\end{cases}$$

> Set one of the variables arbitrarily and solve for the other two: $$x=4,y=3,z=5.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec a=-9\hat i+2\hat j+6\hat k$ and $\vec b=-2\hat i+\hat j+\hat k$

Any vector perpendicular to both $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ would be parallel to $\vec a\times \vec b$ because $\vec a\times \vec b$ always yield a vector perpendicular to both the vectors.

Let the required vector be $\vec c$, hence
$$\vec c=\lambda(\vec a\times \vec b)$$
$$\vec c=\lambda(-4\hat i-3\hat j-5\hat k)=-4\lambda \hat i-3\lambda \hat j-5\lambda\hat k$$